# IIS: How to receive an email notification when file is downloaded using a direct link

Tags: iis, iis-7

Is it possible to configure IIS to send out an email notification when a file inside a certain directory is downloaded? For ex: any file in `www.example.com/download/`?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to poll the IIS log file at a reasonably small interval for the requests you're looking for.

The following powershell script should do what you want. Obviously change the variables to suit your needs.

```
# Directory of IIS log files
$Path = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1"

#Get the most recent log file from the directory
$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1

# Get-Content gets the file, pipe to Where-Object and skip the first 3 lines.
$Log = Get-Content $File.FullName | where {$_ -notLike "#[D,S-V]*" }

# Replace unwanted text in the line containing the columns.
$Columns = (($Log[0].TrimEnd()) -replace "#Fields: ", "" -replace "-","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\)","").Split(" ")

# Count available Columns, used later
$Count = $Columns.Length

# Get all Rows that i Want to retrieve
$QueryString = "*GET*"
$Rows = $Log | where {$_ -like $QueryString}

# Create an instance of a System.Data.DataTable
$IISLog = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "IISLog"

# Loop through each Column, create a new column through Data.DataColumn and add it to the DataTable
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
  $NewColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $Column, ([string])
  $IISLog.Columns.Add($NewColumn)
  }


# Loop Through each Row and add the Rows.
foreach ($Row in $Rows) {
   $Row = $Row.Split(" ")
  $AddRow = $IISLog.newrow()
  for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
    $ColumnName = $Columns[$i]
    $AddRow.$ColumnName = $Row[$i]
  }
   $IISLog.Rows.Add($AddRow)
}

#Format Log data into string for sending
$BodyString = ""
foreach( $Row in $IISLog.Rows ){
    $BodyString = $BodyString + $Row.date + " " + $Row.time + " " + $Row.sip + " " + $Row.csuriquery + "`n"
}

# Variables for sending email
$MailServer = "NAME OF YOUR MAIL SERVER"
$FromAddress = ""
$ToAddress = ""
$Subject = ""
$SMTP = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($MailServer)
$SMTP.Send($FromAddress,$ToAddress,$Subject,$BodyString)
```

I used the following pages for reference.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/46bc6859-d9e3-47c3-b1a6-5132281df18b/howto-use-powershell-to-parse-iis-logs-files?forum=ITCG

http://exchangeserverpro.com/powershell-how-to-send-email/

Comment: Thanks for an alternative approach and the code! Personally I'm trying to avoid interval timed scripts due to performance reasons. But your PowerShell code can still be run manually or maybe even attached to an event like HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do with using the IIS Url Rewrite module and a custom Rewrite Provider. This means you have to write some code, but I just did that for you:

First, you need the [Url Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), that's good to have anyways. Install it an make sure it works.

Next follow the steps in the article [Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module)

There is a code section in that article, replace that with the following:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Net.Mail;
 using Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite;

 public class DownloadAlerter : IRewriteProvider, IProviderDescriptor
 {
     private string recipient, sender, server;

     public void Initialize(IDictionary<string, string> settings, IRewriteContext rewriteContext)
     {
         if (!settings.TryGetValue("Recipient", out recipient) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipient))
             throw new ArgumentException("Recipient provider setting is required and cannot be empty");

         if (!settings.TryGetValue("Sender", out sender) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(sender))
             throw new ArgumentException("Sender provider setting is required and cannot be empty");

         if (!settings.TryGetValue("Server", out server) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(server))
             throw new ArgumentException("Server provider setting is required and cannot be empty");
     }

     public string Rewrite(string value)
     {
         MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
         message.From = new MailAddress(sender);

         message.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));

         message.Subject = "Download Alert";
         message.Body = string.Format("The following URL was downloaded: '{0}'" + Environment.NewLine + "For details check your IIS logs", value);

         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
         client.Host = server;
         client.Send(message);

         return value;
     }

     public IEnumerable<SettingDescriptor> GetSettings()
     {
         yield return new SettingDescriptor("Recipient", "Email address of the recipient");
         yield return new SettingDescriptor("Sender", "Email address of the sender");
         yield return new SettingDescriptor("Server", "The SMTP server to be used");
     }
 }
```

Further down the article describes the changes to your web-config, use something like this instead:

```
 <rewrite>
   <providers>
       <provider name="DownloadAlerter" type="DownloadAlerter, Hahndorf.IIS.DownloadAlertProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx">
           <settings>
               <add key="Recipient" value="peter@******.****" />
               <add key="Sender" value="iis@******.****" />
               <add key="Server" value="localhost" />
           </settings>
       </provider>
   </providers>
   <rules>
       <rule name="Test">
           <match url="specific-page\.html" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="{DownloadAlerter:{URL}}" appendQueryString="false" />
       </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

The `provider type` is the strong name of the provider assembly you created following the article.
The `settings` allow you to specify a server and the recipient.
The `match url` defines for which url you are receiving emails.

This is just a prove of concept, but it worked fine for me. 
I ran into a problem because I tested this on an IIS site that was set to 'No Managed Code', you need to have a `.NET CLR Version` set that matches the version you wrote the provider in.

Also I wasn't able to access anymore information about the request such as the remote IP address, but I haven't looked into that too much.

I uploaded the [project to GitHub.](https://github.com/hahndorf/DownloadAlerter)

Comment: Massive thanks for your effort Peter! I will reflect here on how it works as soon as I implement it.. Less important, but still curious.. Does this approach provide a possibility to know whether the download has been completed successfully? Or is it even possible with any approach?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a all in one solution but look for this :

1- use a software to read iis log and with some "code" email a result when someting match your monitored file . Look for elk stack with email output in logstash . Don't forget to enable logging first .

2- use a web app you code to generate a mail when someone do a get on this file.

Comment: He needs to enable logging on IIS first, "appcmd set config /section:httpLogging /dontLog:False"

Comment: Thanks. Developing a simple web app that uses `/download.php?file=filename` principle was my initial thought. But it requires some time to develop and test, so it's my plan B.